# Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass while showing the list using WP_List_Table

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-list-table

I am working on plugin development and I am getting issues with the table list. I have tried the below code but I am getting an issue called

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as
> array

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('WP_List_Table')) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php');
}

require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php'); // static path

class bl_view_list extends WP_List_Table
{

    /** Text displayed when no customer data is available */
    public function no_items()
    {
        _e('No list avaliable.', 'sp');
    }

    public function get_columns()
    {
        $columns = array(
            'id'          => 'ID',
            'bl_name'       => 'Table name',
            'bl_description' => 'Description',
            'bl_create_date'    => 'Create Date',
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function prepare_items()
    {
        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = array();
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
        $this->items = $this->get_table_data();
        // echo "<pre />";
        // print_r($this->items); // here i am getting correct array output
    }


    // Get table data
    private function get_table_data()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'listdata';
        $get_bl_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from {$table} where bl_is_active=1",);
        return $get_bl_list;
    }


    /**
     * Define what data to show on each column of the table
     *
     * @param  Array $item        Data
     * @param  String $column_name - Current column name
     *
     * @return Mixed
     */
    public function column_default($item, $column_name)
    {
        switch ($column_name) {
            case 'id':
            case 'bl_name':
            case 'bl_description':
            case 'bl_create_date':
                return $item[$column_name];
            default:
                return print_r($item, true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below array output in the prepare_items() function

```
 $this->items = $this->get_table_data();

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [bl_name] => 404-pages.xlsx
            [bl_description] => 404-pages.xlsx
            [bl_create_date] => 2022-11-28 10:16:57
        )
//and so on
)
```

but not sure what I am doing wrong.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does [this question & answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61172811/php-fatal-error-uncaught-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array) help you?

Comment: @kero, No I have checked that on stack overflow before posting the question. My issue is dynamically data not displaying in the table due to that i am getting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $this->items = $this->get_table_data();
```

If this line is triggering the error, then the reason is probably that `items` should be an array of arrays, not an array of stdClass objects. But you don't need to change much, as [`get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) does support returning arrays instead of objects (which is the default).

Instead of

```
$get_bl_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from {$table} where bl_is_active=1",);
```

do

```
$get_bl_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from {$table} where bl_is_active=1", ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. I have added ARRAY_A and it's started working